# Error when processing unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, wxpython, py2app

I've got a wxPython app that I made into an app using py2app. It's worked fine for a while, and without changing anything that I know of, I suddenly get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)`. I didn't change the file in any way. I didn't even rebuild the app, it's the same one I've been using, nothing different whatsoever. I've heard this can happen if "the terminal is not set to UTF-8", but this app doesn't use a terminal, and I haven't changed any settings in my terminal since it ran fine.

EDIT: I discovered the problem is that I have a line which does `os.listdir()`. The directory now contains a filename with a `ü`. Why does this error occur? Shouldn't it just change it from a string into a unicode type?

Comment: What's your input? A file? Can you paste the line of code that's throwing the exception?

Comment: When your program exits it should contain a stack trace including a line number. Can you provide the exact line that is failing?

Comment: @Fuzzyfelt It's running as a .app, just says something like `AppName has encountered an error and needs to close: SomeError: variable x referenced before assignment`. But I already know what's causing the error, I just needed to know how to fix it (jro answered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a unicode string to `os.listdir`. When doing so, the filenames will be decoded using the filesystem's encoding.

```
import os
>>> os.listdir(u'c:\\')
[u'$Recycle.Bin', u'Config.Msi', u'Documents and Settings', u'hiberfil.sys', (...)]
```